# Application Insights Telemetry Collection for VSC Extension

Tags: typescript, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-application-insights

I'm developing an extension in Visual Studio Code (for Visual Studio Code) and I'm using Application Insights to collect telemetry data.

I want to send all the information I've collect to Application Insights before they exit the session.

I tried using the following code (which is in Typescript) to do so, but it doesn't work:

```js
context.subscriptions.push(
        //First apporach that didn't work
                // new vscode.Disposable(() => {
                //  telemetryInst.sendExperiment();
                //  telemetryInst.sendData(trial);
                //  console.log("Sent Telemetry");
                // })

                //second approach
                {
                    dispose: () => {
                        telemetryInst.sendExperiment();
                        telemetryInst.sendData(trial);
            console.log("Sent Telemetry");
                    }
                }
);
```

I don't know of any other approach that I can take to send data to Application Insights before the user exits the session (the session in which they are using my extension).

Comment: one method of sending data with custom events will share you the process

Answer (score 1):

```
import  {  ApplicationInsights  }  from  '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
const  appInsights = new  ApplicationInsights({
config:  {
instrumentationKey:  'd03e30b9-6973-4f6c-8a3c-e9f2cf5a8ec1',

},
});

appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.trackPageView();

Application Insights
function  sendCustomEvent(eventName: string,  properties?: { [key: string]: any  })  {
appInsights.trackEvent({  name:  eventName,  properties  });
}
sendCustomEvent("CustomEvent",  {  key1:  "2",  key2:  "3"  });
console.log("Sent Telemetry...");
```

[image]

**For exception:**

```js
appInsights.loadAppInsights();

try  {

const  someUndefinedVariable: any = undefined;  // Placeholder variable

const  result = someUndefinedVariable.undefinedFunction();

}  catch (error) {

appInsights.trackException({  exception:  error  });

}
```

[image]

**For success:**

```js
const  someVariable: any = 'Hello, World!';  
console.log(someVariable);
appInsights.trackEvent({  name:  'OperationSuccess',  properties:  {  message:  'Operation succeeded'  }  });
```

[image]

**Custom message and security level:**

```java
appInsights.trackTrace({ message: 'Operation succeeded: Hello, World!', severityLevel: 1 });
```

[image]

For more details refer to this [azure-docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics.md) for the Application Insights API for custom events and metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Sampath, but the primary issue that I'm having is sending telemetry information to Azure before the user exits the session. I know how to send the information to Azure, but I'm not sure how to send it right when they exit VSC.

Comment: Sorry I think your misunderstanding my question again, I know how to and am able to send information to Azure Application insights, I have no problem with that. The problem I'm having is finding a way to send the information when the user exits VSC. So my issue is not with application insights or sending telemetry, rather defining a function that is called on when the user is exiting VSC.

Comment: you can send login and log out like this  function ```sendLogoutTelemetryToAppInsights(username) {
  // Replace this with your code to send logout telemetry to Azure Application Insights
  appInsights.trackEvent({ name: 'UserLogout', properties: { username } });
}


function performLogin(username) {
  

  
  sendLoginTelemetryToAppInsights(username);
}


function performLogout(username) {
  

  
  sendLogoutTelemetryToAppInsights(username);
}``` but cannot send the log after exiting the application and visual studio code.

Comment: So is it not possible to log information to Azure after exiting the application?

Comment: Yes, @BerryCherolds .